# a hypothetical measuring tape and cylinder

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

[image]

Note: the blue arrow just shows the direction at which the measuring tape wraps/loops on the cylinder.

A measuring tape with zero thickness starts off from the zero-unit mark to the 13-unit mark vertically in line with the center of a 12.5-unit radius cylinder's cross section, before bending and wrapping/looping around the cylinder. After looping, it joins back to the 13-unit mark and traces vertically again to the zero-unit mark.

At what unit mark does the zero-unit mark line up with so that the 100-unit mark is horizontally in line with the cross section's center?

Alternatively, an equation I could get from this is 100 = 13 + x + 12.5(π + θ), where x is the length of that section of tape measure approaching the cylinder, and θ is the angle, from the horizontal line, where the tape tangents the cylinder. But from there, I don't know how to proceed to finding x or θ. All I could think of is that as the 13-unit mark gets closer to the cylinder's center, θ would increase.

Comment: There is a range of solutions , depending on the point of departure.

Comment: @Moti actually no. The first part of the question gets rids of that ambiguity. Check my answer below

Comment: You are right. If the answer does not satisfy you, will solve it for you:)

Comment: I will just point out that first you need to solve the second part of the problem to get the first part that is not defined well.

Comment: Is the tape for both cases 100? How you want to define the zero unit location - as distance from the circle?

Comment: Hi, can you please check if my answer is right? If not can you comment so that I may correct the answer?

Comment: I've replied to the comments, and I'll also append the equation I've thought of into the question for further clarification.

Comment: @Moti I surmised that the point of departure/entry/tangency of the tape measure to the cylinder is dependent on the given as to where the 100-unit mark is positioned at.

Comment: @Gregory The equation you get includes a sum of $\theta$ and $tan{\theta}$

Comment: Use GeoGebra for an estimated solution (is accuracy of second decimal ok?)

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to find the length of the line between the bend and the point it touches the circle up until the horizontal line. Let the length be $x$. This can be found out from the first part of the question. Length of the tape = $100$ units and this must be equal to $13 + x + \pi 12.5 + x + 13. \implies x$ is $17.36$ units.
[image]

Now to the second part, we need one end of the tape to end at the horizontal line. Let the length of the tape before the bend be $y$. Then we must have $100 = y + 17.36 + \pi 12.5, y = 43.38$. The zero unit mark would then be at $43.38 - 13 = 30.38$units
[image]

Sorry for my shoddy art work.

Comment: The tape is touching the circle at a point that need to be calculated - the portion of the circle is larger than half of it.

Comment: @Moti I have added an image to further clarify this. My $x$ doesn't rely upon the point where the tape contacts the circle

Comment: I agree with @Moti. The arc beyond half the circle needs to be taken into account. In equation form, it would be 100 = 13 + x + 12.5(π + θ), where x is the length of that section of tape measure approaching the cylinder, and θ is the angle, from the horizontal line, where the tape tangents the cylinder. But from there, I don't know how to proceed to finding x or θ.

Comment: @GregoryLeo you are making it unnecessarily complicated, by assuming $x$ the way you are.  Instead assume that $x$ is the length from the point where it departs the vertical line till the dashed horizontal line. You don't need $\theta$ or any other parameter value then

Comment: Furthermore @GregoryLeo, there is no merit in finding $\theta$ or the length of the tangent to the circle as the next part also takes into account the whole length from the vertical line to the horizontal dashed line. This is also precisely why there is no data given to find $\theta$, because it is not required